# Unable to get new selected value of @Html.DropDownListFor in case of using autobinding

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Unable to bind model with value from @Html.DropDownListFor field in MVC3 (razor) of a strongly typed view.

Model used for strongly typed view:

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string Name{get;set;}
  pulic int Status_ID{get;set;}
}
```

In strongly typed view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m.Status_ID, new SelectList(Repo.AllStatus, "ID", Name"), new   {@style = "width: 100%;" })
```

Before submitting the form I selected the option with ID=24(i.e. value=24 option is selected)

In controller

```
public ActionResult AddMyModel(MyModel myModel)
{

}
```

While debugging, in controller, I got that:
 myModel.Name is expected value but
 myModel.Status_ID is 0 not 24

where am I going wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass in a view model to your view with all the statuses already populated.

Here is a solution to your problem. Modify it to fit in with your scenario. I hope I haven't left out anything. The code below is what I am assuming your models might look like.

Your status class:

```
public class Status
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On your view you need to pass in a view model that contains a list of all your statuses:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public int StatusId { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<Status> Statuses { get; set; }
}
```

Your controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
     private readonly IStatusRepository statusRepository;

     public YourController(IStatusRepository statusRepository)
     {
          this.statusRepository = statusRepository;
     }

     public ActionResult YourAction()
     {
          YourViewModel viewModel = new YourViewModel
          {
               Statuses = statusRepository.FindAll()
          };

          return View(viewModel);
     }
}
```

And then your view will look something like this:

```
@model YourProject.ViewModels.Statuses.YourViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(
     x => x.StatusId,
     new SelectList(Model.Statuses, "Id", "Name", Model.StatusId),
     "-- Select --"
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.StatusId)
```

I hope this can help you in the right direction and shed some light on what you are trying to achieve.